# Google Knowledge Graph periodic appearance

Tags: seo, google, knowledge-graph

When searching for my client's business name in Google, the knowledge graph appears sometimes, and other times I simply get a local map showing the business, with no knowledge graph. Baffled as to why. Any ideas? My client has a Google+ Business page.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure there is an answer for this. Google does what it does and who knows how or why it makes the decisions it does. In computer science, computers will do the same thing over and over unless instructed not to. There is likely several criteria that we are not privy to that we will never know that controls what is shown on the SERP page from the knowledge graph. You and I are trained to think that it is reasonable to think the results should be consistent when it may be the code says No. I cannot wait to see what answers you get. Here's hoping for something good! Cheers!!

Comment: Have an upvote. Cause I'm sure many, many people would like to know an answer to this question.

Comment: @closetnoc, - Perhaps an answer may be bandwidth on the client side. Additionally may be bandwidth/traffic on the server (Google Side) to a given network segment or routing node. Again , a guess that is probably wrong but I can see no logical algorithm that would cause a switch between an area map with multiple listings and a domain/entity specific knowledge panel, except a bandwidth issue .

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the browser you're using as well, because if you're signed in to Google, the Search results will be personalised to your previous searches. When I check SERPs for clients I would always log into google in incognito mode, to remove all personalisation.

Similarly, it may be the location you're searching from, if you download moz bar for chrome (available in the chrome store), you can 'spoof' your location to make google think you're actually somewhere else in country, and this allows you to see what other people 'see' if their location is not close to the business.

It may be a case that Google thinks you're near it, therefore shows you the map instead of knowledge graph